# Substitution Nonlinear Differential Equation Problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So my problem was to solve the differential equation $y^2y'' = y'$.

Let $u = y'$. Therefore $y^2 u' = u$ and integral $du = \int 1/y^2$.

Case 1: $c=0, y_1 = \int of 1/y^2 = -1/y + c_1$;

Case 2: $c =a^2>0$, $y_2 = \int {1\over y^2+a^2}$, $dy = {1 \over a} \arctan\left(\frac{y}{a}\right) + c_2$

Case 3: $c =-a^2<0$, $y' = {1\over y^2-a^2}\,dy = {1\over (y-a)(y+a)}$ 
      then $y = \frac{-1}{2a}  [\ln|y+a|-\ln|y-a|] + c_3$
       so $y_3 = \frac{-1}{2a} \ln\left|\frac{x+a}{x-a}\right| + c_3$

Does this seem like a reasonable approach to encasing all the solutions?

Comment: Hi Disha Wan ! You introduces a the constant $c$ which is not defined before being used. You write :  integral $du = \int 1/y^2$ which is non-sens since the non consistancy of notation (integration with respect to what variable ? . $d?$ missing into the integral).

Answer (score 2):

$$y^2y''=y'$$
$y=0$ is a trivial solution.

Case $y\neq 0$ :
$$y''=\frac{y'}{y^2}$$
After integration :
$$y'=-\frac{1}{y}+c_1$$
With $y'=\frac{dy}{dx}$
$$dx=\frac{y}{c_1y-1}dy$$
After integration :
$$x=\frac{1}{c_1^2}(c_1y+\ln|1-c_1y|)+c_2$$
If necessary, the inverse function $y(x)$ can be expressed thanks to the LambertW function.
$$e^{c_1y}|1-c_1y|=e{c_1^2(x-c_2)}$$
$$(c_1y-1)e^{c_1y-1}=\pm e^{c_1^2(x-c_2)-1}$$
$$c_1y-1=W\left(\pm e^{c_1^2(x-c_2)-1}  \right)$$
$W(X)$ is the LambertW function, where $X=\pm e^{c_1^2(x-c_2)-1}$
$$y(x)=\frac{W\left(\pm e^{c_1^2(x-c_2)-1}  \right)+1}{c_1}$$

Comment: Aren't there two cases when y is not equal to zero?

Comment: Also, how can this be expressed in terms of y(x)?

Comment: Do you know the LambertW function? This is required to express $y(x)$

Comment: Yes, is this the only possible way to express y(x)?

Comment: Sure ! It is. But depending on the boundary conditions (missing in the wording of the question) some particular values of $c_1$ and $c_2$ may lead to simplification of the resulting function in particular cases.